# what is the d4e56740 folder?

Tags: installation

I'm trying to save some space so I tried a `geth removedb` and then a `--fast` resync.

But while browsing my `.ethereum` folder I saw this one which looks like a chaindata folder given its contents and is massive, 10Gb, what is its use ?

The `geth removedb` doesn't remove it, is it safe to delete it ?

Comment: The name of the folder is the hex representation of the first 4 bytes of the genesis block hash - `eth.getBlock(0).hash` gives the result `"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you ve excuted an  `geth removedb` which remove Geth's blockchain and state databases.
and then you excuted `geth --fast` which enables fast syncing through state downloads instead downloading the full block data (condensed chain data) so you should have a chaindata folder with XGo. So you deleted an old chain and synced to a new one.

**when you have this d4e56740 (inside you will find another blockchain :blocks,states..) folder it means you used another Ethereum Client besides geth client or multiple instances geth clients**

Comment: Which client you know?

Comment: did you use any other client eth,parity .. or did your run multiple geth instance?

Comment: I used eth a while ago and I regularly run multiple geth

Comment: that's why you have separated folder=separated blockchains

Comment: That is why because of eth or the multiple geth

Comment: so if you don't need the data inside just remove it